# Android paging library getItem raisesIllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I'm using the [Architecture component's paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) with RecyclerView

When Overriding getItemViewType I call

```
getItem(position)
```

Calling the same function in "OnBindViewHolder" works like a charm

Here is the Stack Trace

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page size can change only if last page is only one present
>           at android.arch.paging.PagedStorage.allocatePlaceholders(PagedStorage.java:404)
>           at android.arch.paging.TiledPagedList.loadAroundInternal(TiledPagedList.java:156)
>           at android.arch.paging.PagedList.loadAround(PagedList.java:398)
>           at android.arch.paging.AsyncPagedListDiffer.getItem(AsyncPagedListDiffer.java:201)
>           at android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter.getItem(PagedListAdapter.java:156)
>           at me.ekhaled1619.redditur.ui.PostsAdapter.getItemViewType(PostsAdapter.kt:75)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5880)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5812)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5808)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3878)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3595)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4148)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:625)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:727)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17551)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5614)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2379)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2106)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1283)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6358)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:873)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:685)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:859)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6365)
>   2018-06-24 22:37:11.892 26173-26173/me.ekhaled1619.redditur E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:883)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)